# Ecryptfs does not seem to encrypt home folder

Tags: ubuntu, bash, encryption, ecryptfs

**System:** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64 ["bento"](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04) vagrant box with VirtualBox 5.

**Steps:**

```
root@vagrant:~# adduser --encrypt-home citizenfour
root@vagrant:~# ssh citizenfour@localhost

citizenfour@vagrant:~$ echo "abcdefg" > secret.txt
citizenfour@vagrant:~$ chmod 0600 secret.txt
citizenfour@vagrant:~$ exit

root@vagrant:~# cat ~citizenfour/secret.txt 
# abcdefg
```

**Question:** Why can `root` still read `citizenfour`'s secret even though we set up encryption for `citizenfour`'s home folder? I.e. why was `secret.txt` not encrypted on logout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reboot the computer (or in your case do vagrant reload) after logging in with you citizenfour user.

Comment: Okay, that works, but seems a little awkward, as most users on a server do not have the right to reboot it. Can you explain what triggers the re-encryption of the home directory and why it does not happen directly after logging off?

Comment: Extended discussion: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=98227